# How do I hide an element when a certain slide has a class of active in fullpage.js slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js and have a fixed element on the page that needs to change according to what slide is active. So basically if slide 1 is active, then fixed element 1 is showing. If slide 2 is active, then fixed element 2 is showing instead and so on. Nothing is working for me and I can't figure out why.

```
$('.fp-slidesNav a').click(function() {
        var activeSlide = $('.slide.active');
        if ((activeSlide).hasClass('slide1')) {
            $('fixedelement1').show();
            $('fixedelement1').siblings().hide();
        }
        else if ((activeSlide).hasClass('slide2')) {
            $('fixedelement2').show();
            $('fixedelement2').siblings().hide();
        }
       else if {
         ...
       }
});
```

It's possible that I have a class name wrong or there is a typo somewhere in all my code, but I don't think so because I checked everything multiple times. It's weird because I can do

```
 $('a').click(function() {
       alert('hello');
});
```

and when I click on the .fp-slidesNav a anchor and get no alert but click on another random link and I get the alert.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: u may use this event https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex , and based on the index show hide your fixed elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
**afterSlideLoad (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex)**

Callback fired once the slide of a section have been loaded, after the scrolling has ended. Parameters:

> anchorLink: anchorLink corresponding to the section.
>
> index: index of the section. Starting from 1.
>
> slideAnchor: anchor corresponding to the slide (in case there is)
>
> slideIndex: index of the slide. Starting from 1. (the default slide doesn't count as slide, but as a section)

In case of not having anchorLinks defined for the slide or slides the slideIndex parameter would be the only one to use. Example:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
        var loadedSlide = $(this);

        //first slide of the second section
        if(anchorLink == 'secondPage' && slideIndex == 1){
            alert("First slide loaded");
        }

        //second slide of the second section (supposing #secondSlide is the
        //anchor for the second slide
        if(index == 2 && slideIndex == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Second slide loaded");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is probably what I need but unfortunately when I add it in the options it breaks the slider by pushing everything up out of the screen, so that prevents me from using the slider. I'll have to play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think @KishoreSahas is right. but few changes / improvisations

assuming ur fixedelement on the page looks similar to the below. may be section tag with child div tags

```
<ul id="fixedelement">
  <li class="slide firstPage active"></li>
  <li class="slide secondPage "></li>
  <li class="slide thirdPage "></li>
  <li class="slide fourthPage "></li>

</ul>
```

your slider code needs to look like below

```
$('#myslider').fullpage({
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage']
  afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    $('#fixedelement .slide').each(function () {$(this).hide();}
    $('#fixedelement .' + anchorLink).each(function () {$(this).show();}
  }
});
```

I have never used the fullpage.js before so the above code is not tested.

Comment: Thanks but afterSlideLoad seems to be working for me, I just had to change the example some.